# Process cookies before any controller action is invoked in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cookies

Where can I put some code that will be executed before any controller action is executed ?

I'm trying to replace default ASP.NET Session and I need to do this before any controller actions take place:
get the cookies collection and check if I have new visitor with no cookies - than I'd add new "session ID" cookie that will than be available to the controllers. Otherwise (if there already is some "session ID" cookie) I will not do anything.

Where can I place the code that will do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC 3 now has the Global Action Filters which will run for every controller:

Scott Guthrie's Overview: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/27/introducing-asp-net-mvc-3-preview-1.aspx
MSDN details on Filter Types: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416513(VS.98).aspx

Answer (score 4):

I do it in Global.asax.cs

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            var c = Request.Cookies["lang"];
...
}
```

Comment: Is this also known as "Global Action Filter"? And same as the answer from Ryan Tofteland (https://stackoverflow.com/a/5278977/1779091)?

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of places you could do this, I'd say that the best place would be in an ActionFilter, overriding the OnActionExecuting event.  If you want it to happen first, then you'll want to add the Order setting when you apply it.

If you want *all* your controllers to have it, then you could apply that filter to a base class, or just override the base class's OnActionExecuting method.

As a side note, for maximum testability you probably should have your *not* directly access the cookies collection in the request; that information (if needed) should come into the action method as a parameter or as a property on the controller that you can set in tests.

If you need to wire into the lifecycle earlier than OnActionExecuting (for any reason) you could also create a custom ControllerFactory, but I think that's probably overkill bsed on your description.

Comment: Sorry to hijack, but you got me thinking. If, for some reason, I want to pull a cookie value into the route values for use as a parameter on an action method, I would probably want to do that in a new base controller's OnActionExecuting? Or would it already be too late at that point to be used in deciding which action method to call?

Comment: @patridge: In my case I don't need to manipulate or change which action method is going to be called.I just need to put something to the Cookies collection... But maybe you are asking this at generally (than you may consider creating your own question)

Comment: @patridge> afaik, you would register a custom IValueProvider in that case, to extract them and let them be used in routing & model binding (not positive on this, but pretty sure). You could alternatively use an ActionSelectionAttribute to do what you're looking for, but ime they're more trouble than they're worth for anything non-trivial.

Answer (score 3):

A custom [IHttpModule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttpmodule.aspx) will do the trick.

Comment: Do I have access to `Request` property from `IHttpModule` implementing class or is there any other way to get an instance of `HttpRequest` from implementing class ? I need it to be able to get cookies collection.

Comment: Looks like you would. In the sample from the MSDN link, they get to it in the implementation by way of the event source argument. For example, in their `HttpApplication.BeginRequest` handler: `((HttpApplication)source).Context.Request`.

Answer (score 0):

On your global.asax:

```
 protected void Application_Start()
        {
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
            RegisterWebApiFilters(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters);
        }

public static void RegisterWebApiFilters(System.Web.Http.Filters.HttpFilterCollection filters)
        {
            filters.Add(new CredentialsActionFilter());
        }
```

The CredentialsActionFilter class:

```
 public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            var cookies = actionContext.Request.Headers.GetCookies("credentials").FirstOrDefault();
            string username = cookies.Cookies.Where(c => c.Name == "username").FirstOrDefault().Value;
            actionContext.Request.Properties.Add("username", username); // so you can access the value from within your actions
        }
```